# Update a column paratitioned by another column

Tags: sql

I have a table that 2 columns look like this:

```
basedon                        line
MM2013000028
MM2013000028
MM2013000028
MM2013000029
MM2013000030
MM2013000030
```

The line number is currently blank but should be:

```
basedon                   line
MM2013000028              001
MM2013000028              002
MM2013000028              003
MM2013000029              001
MM2013000030              001
MM2013000030              002
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you get the row number (partitioned by baseon) and update the result set:

```
WITH r_SomeTable
AS
(
SELECT *
, row_number() over(partition by baseon order by baseon) as rnk
FROM SomeTable
)

UPDATE r_SomeTable
SET line = rnk
GO
```

You can look at this question for more details:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ee06f451-c418-4bca-8288-010410e8cf14/update-table-using-rownumber-over

Comment: How do you know OP is using SQL Server?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, lots of people who use Microsoft SQL Server only tag their questions `sql`. So it's not an unreasonable default assumption.

Comment: @BillKarwin I try to avoid assumptions.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, I assumed as much.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make `line field an integer type` rather than a string. You can always select data as you need with front zeros. Or if it is  for presentation purpose, you should do it on the client application.

If you are on `Sql-Server` try something like this (**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fae3/6)**):

```
Declare @Number int = 0
Update t set  @Number = line = @Number + 1

--Assuming you have only 999 records (i.e 3 digits). 
--Please modify as needed.
Select basedon, right('00' + convert(varchar(2), line),3) line  
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTableName
SET line = ISNULL(SELECT MAX(line) FROM MyTableName, 0) + 1
```